# Rotation stops when I clone a unity project with git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I have a project in Unity where there are some logos that rotate on themselves, those logos are imported from blender, to make them rotate well use this guide [fix rotation unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-FixZAxisIsUp.html).
Well, when you upload them to a git repository, and make a clone of the project, the logos have stopped rotating. That could be happening?

In the local project (which is not uploaded to the git) the logos rotate perfectly. It only fails when doing a project clone or pull.

this is my .gitignore:

```
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/UWP/
/Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Visual Studio 2015 cache directory
/.vs/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

#Project specific
test_Data/
```

This is my script rotation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// Spin the object at a specified speed
/// </summary>
public class SpinFree : MonoBehaviour {
    [Tooltip("Spin: Yes or No")]
    public bool spin;
    [Tooltip("Spin the parent object instead of the object this script is attached to")]
    public bool spinParent;
    public float speed = 10f;

    public bool clockwise = true;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float direction = 1f;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float directionChangeSpeed = 2f;


    public Axis axis = Axis.Y;

    void Update() {
        if (direction < 1f) {
            direction += Time.deltaTime / (directionChangeSpeed / 2);
        }
        Vector3 rotation;

        switch(axis)
        {
            case Axis.X:
                rotation = Vector3.right;
                break;
            case Axis.Z:
                rotation = Vector3.forward;
                break;
            default:
                rotation = Vector3.up;
                break;
        }

        if (spin) {
            if (clockwise) {
                if (spinParent)
                    transform.parent.transform.Rotate(rotation, (speed * direction) * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
                else
                    transform.Rotate(rotation, (speed * direction) * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            } else {
                if (spinParent)
                    transform.parent.transform.Rotate(-rotation, (speed * direction) * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
                else
                    transform.Rotate(-rotation, (speed * direction) * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Axis
    {
        X, Y, Z
    };

}
```

This is Spin script configuration:
[image]

This is my Project Settings configuration:

[image]

Comment: Are .meta files set to visible in the editor settings?

Comment: That option must be visible before uploading files to git? I have it in non-visible, the change to visible and the logos are still not rotated.

Comment: This is basically not solvable without knowing your gitignore and how exactly you set stuff up in your project ... it sounds like the rotation is a script or animation?

Comment: Rotation is a script that works correctly.
The configuration of my .gitignore I update it in the question.